# While numbering the record of a difference only in the SQL server, you want to get

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL server, I want to realize that such following manner,
I want to have only resolve SQL
Someone, please tell me.

**Table A**

```
col1
---------
AAAAA   
BBBBB    
CCCCC   
DDDDD    
EEEEE
```

**Table B**

```
id | col1  | insertDate
------------------
1  | AAAAA | 2015/4/1 
2  | BBBBB | 2015/4/1    
3  | CCCCC | 2015/4/1
```

The expected table
(SQL execution: 2015/4/2)

```
id | col1  | insertDate
------------------
1  | AAAAA | 2015/4/1 
2  | BBBBB | 2015/4/1 
3  | CCCCC | 2015/4/1 
4  | DDDDD | 2015/4/2
5  | EEEEE | 2015/4/2
```

I want to create a SQL that you can get a table as described above

SQL to extract the record is not in the table A was able to

```
select
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by col1) as id,
    col1,
    SYSDATETIME() as insertDate
from A 
where
not exists(
    select col1 
    from B
    where B.col1 = A.col1
)
```

Comment: So you want to merge the days in a query to get any records that are present in table A but not in table B with today's date and an identity/ row number column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to get all the rows from TableA but only the matching rows from TableB. Then just check if TableB.insertDate IS NULL.

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS id
,       col1
,       ISNULL(TableB.insertDate, SYSDATETIME()) AS insertDate
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.col1 = TableB.col1
```

Comment: Thanks you!
To be able to get the expected value, we are very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tablea.col1) AS id
       ,tablea.col1
       ,ISNULL(TableB.insertDate, SYSDATETIME()) AS insertDate
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.col1 = TableB.col1
```

(OR)

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tablea.col1) AS id
       ,tablea.col1
       ,ISNULL(TableB.insertDate, dateadd(day,-1,SYSDATETIME()) )AS insertDate 
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.col1 = TableB.col1
```

Hope this will help you.